# Slick slider text on top of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to make a pretty normal carousel, with two arrows on either side in the vertical middle, and text with a button in the middle on top of the image. I cannot get anything to appear on top of the image though, even though the arrows and text are all absolute and have a higher z-index. Here's a codepen with my code. http://codepen.io/kathryncrawford/pen/AXmVAz

And here's my HTML

```
<div class="slick-slider">
    <div>
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.placecage.com/1500/750" alt="">
        <div class="info">
        <h1 class="slider-heading">Heading</h1>
            <p class="slider-subheading lead">Subheading</p>
            <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="">button text</a>
        <p class="down-arrow">
            <a class="btn btn-large btn-down-arrow" href="#theend">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.placecage.com/1500/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.placecage.com/1500/750" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS (the slick css is not included here, but it is in the codepen)

```
  .slick-slider img { /* keep images full screen */
    width: 100%;
  }

  .chevron-container { /* full slider height container for chevrons */
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .slick-right { /* keeps right arrow to the right */
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .chevron-container > .fa { /* positions chevrons in vertical center */
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10em;
    height: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 5em;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .slick-slider .info {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .slick-slider .info > div {
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

And my JS

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.slick-slider').slick({
    accessibility: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    nextArrow: '<div class="chevron-container slick-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></div>',
    prevArrow: '<div class="chevron-container"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></div>',
    slidesToShow: 1
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do

```
.slick-slide {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
}
```

so that the `.info` stuff knows it should be absolutely positioned to it's parent.

Comment: You're correct, but `.slick-slide` (not `slider`) is *not* set to `position:relative;`, once you do that, it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative` to `.slide-slide`.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.slick-slider').slick({
    accessibility: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    nextArrow: '<div class="chevron-container slick-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></div>',
    prevArrow: '<div class="chevron-container"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></div>',
    slidesToShow: 1
  });
});
```

```css
.slick-slider
{
  position: relative;

  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
  position: relative;

  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
  outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
  display: table;

  content: &#39;&#39;;
}
.slick-track:after
{
  clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}
[dir=&#39;rtl&#39;] .slick-slide
{
  float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
  display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
  display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
  pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
  display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
  display: block;

  height: auto;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.slick-slider img { /* keep images full screen */
  width: 100%;
}

.chevron-container { /* full slider height container for chevrons */
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}

.slick-right { /* keeps right arrow to the right */
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.chevron-container > .fa { /* positions chevrons in vertical center */
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10em;
  height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 5em;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slick-slider .info {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slick-slider .info > div {
  display: inline-block !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<div class="slick-slider">
  <div>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.placecage.com/1500/750" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="slider-heading">Heading</h1>
      <p class="slider-subheading lead">Subheading</p>
      <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="">button text</a>
      <p class="down-arrow">
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-down-arrow" href="#theend">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.placecage.com/1500/750" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.placecage.com/1500/750" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KathrynCrawford yes its added to `.slick-slider` but not added in `.slick-slide`.

Comment: Oh! Duh! It's always something simple isn't it. Thanks!