# Text on top of images with Slick Slider and Bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am using slick slider http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and would like to place text on top of the image. Therefore I use bootstrap carousel-caption, which works just fine for any image. Problem with slick slider is that the text shows, but seems to be not on the highest "level". That is, it seems there is some layer above the text as I cannot highlight the text or click on the text link.

I did some research and almost all posts state I should use a position:relative to make the z-index work properly. For example this post: [Slick slider text on top of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853757/slick-slider-text-on-top-of-images)

However, changing the position as suggested in the answers to the post above does not make any difference, and also changing z-index does not work.

```css
.carousel-caption {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  bottom: initial
  z-index: 1200;
}

.slick-slide, .slick-track, .slick-list, .slick-slide-fade {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
}
```

For the full code please see my fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gnrqhk32/6/#&togetherjs=4RVVzljQI4

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired result? Maybe image or something? Currently it is quite hard to understand what is wrong. Also resetting `position` style for slick internals may break slider.

Comment: Can you open the fiddle link and then try to click on "test link 1" in the middle of the slider. You cannot click it because some layer is on top of text.  So my desire result is to have the text as "highest" layer, being able to click on that text link. Everything else should stay "visually" the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
.slick-slide, .slick-track, .slick-list, .slick-slide-fade {
  /* ... */
  position: relative;
  z-index:100;
}
```

add that css code and you will be able to click the link and the dots

Delete the z-index you have in the .carousel-caption.

I was able to click both options.. please check and let me know

Comment: not working because this way I cannot click on the dots anymore.

Comment: Check now and let me know!

Comment: now the link is again not clickable, doesn't work

Comment: I change exactly as you said, but it does not work.

Comment: It works for me!!.. Did you delete the z-index from .carousel-caption?

Comment: yes I did delete that. https://jsfiddle.net/gnrqhk32/6/ what am I missing?

Comment: sorry the fiddle was on collaboration, seems someone reversed my edits. Its working now. thanks!