# Slick Slider z-index issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm using slick slider and have created the following custom layout with it.

[image: Slick Slider]

And what I'm attempting to do now is to put text and buttons on top of the slides that users can high light or click. Upon searching for this issue, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853757/slick-slider-text-on-top-of-images) which I followed and added

```
position: relative;
```

To both the main class of the slide `my_slider` and the individual slides `slick-slide`

However, this didn't work for me. So what I did was add a `z-index:1` to the `slick-slide` class and `z-index: 2;` to the button. But this didn't work either. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've recreated the issue in a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kf6ohz98/3/

Comment: You fiddle doesn't seems to show a working demo. Can you consider updating it with the slick init?

Comment: My apologies. I saved fiddle before adding javascript and then forgot to get new updated link after I added it. Post has been updated with proper link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until [this feature request](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/826) is added, you can resort to the below solution.

For highlighting the text, you may remove the below styles from `.slick-slider{...}` in the **actual** slick.css file.

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Or it can be overridden using the below code in **your** css file.

```
.slick-slider{
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  -moz-user-select: auto;
  -ms-user-select: auto;
  user-select: auto;
}
```

Now you need to reset the `translate3d(0, 0, 0);` in `.my_slider` using below,

```
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
  -ms-transform: none !important;
  -o-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

Also, note that the button click and highlighting is not working because of a **second reason** as the `.slider-nav-thumbnails` is overlapping the `.my_slider`.

To get rid of this, you can set `z-index: 1;` to the `.my_slider` as its already positioned `relative`.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5b8akzot/26/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the css to both my local and my fiddle and neither are working. https://jsfiddle.net/kf6ohz98/5/

Comment: Awesome. This works. I'll accept your answer. But I'm a bit confused. What exactly did you add?

Comment: I have updated my answer and also included a new fiddle. Please have a look. Thank you.